# Can't access Linux Samba share from OSX

Tags: linux, macos, samba

I have a samba share in an arch linux server, that I cannot access from OSX, but I can access it normally from any Windows machine. When I try to access it from the terminal (from OSX) with the anonymous user it returns an authentication error:

```
$ smbutil view -a //192.168.1.154/data
smbutil: server rejected the authentication: Authentication error
```

When I try to access it with guest access I get:

```
$ smbutil view -g //192.168.1.154/data
smbutil: server connection failed: Invalid argument
```

Here is my smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = Shares
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad User
        logfile = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        max log size = 50
        dns proxy = no

[data]
        path = /mnt/data
        guest ok = yes
        read only = no
        browsable = yes
        force user = nobody
        force group = nobody
        create mask = 0755
        directory mask = 0755
```

Comment: Anything in the smb log on the Linux box?

Comment: Not really. In fact, there is no evidence of me trying to access it.

Comment: is this related? http://serverfault.com/questions/773370/ubuntu-anonymous-samba-share-now-not-accessible-from-osx-machine

Comment: Maybe related: https://superuser.com/questions/1648510/writable-samba-share-ends-up-read-only/1649058#1649058

Answer (score 2):

In Finder, choose Go -> Connect to Server, and in the server address box enter

smb://somedomain%5csomeuser@someserver/path/to/data

```
  somedomain is the domain you log in via as if logged onto the windows machine, 
  someuser is your user id, 
  someserver is server hosting the share you're trying to access
  /path/to/data is the rest of the path to the location you want
```

Comment: Late to the game, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me worked setting password for samba account:

`sudo smbpasswd -a NEW_PASSWORD`

...I thought linux account is shared to samba but you need to set password extra to samba.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Bug in Samba affecting OSX clients. It drove me mad!

https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11847

Comment: Answers should contain quote and cite all relevant information from links

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but when trying to connect from mac os sierra to a windows host. I tried on a second macbook pro and same thing. Eentually I traced it back to the date and time on the windows machine. If the date/time is out by more the 1 hour then client connection fails. I synched the times to be the same and voila.