# Writable samba share ends up read only

Tags: docker, samba

I have problems setting up a docker samba server (dperspon/samba) on my server (Pi4). The writable samba share appears to be read only. However the behavior is weird. When I put a file into the share using MacOS Finder a file is created, but it stays empty. The operation fails with the following note *The operation could not be completed because an unknown error occurred (error -50)*. Using CLI everything is fine. The storage (/media/data) is ExFat formated. What is wrong with the following compose file?

```yaml
  samba:
    image: dperson/samba
    container_name: samba
    command: -g "log level = 2" -u "root;PASSWORD" -s "all;/smb/all;yes;no;no;root"
    volumes:
      - /media/data:/smb/all
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - WORKGROUP=media
      #- USERID=0
      #- GROUPID=0
    ports:
      - 139:139
      - 445:445
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This is the resulting conf in the container.

```
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   create mask = 0664
   force create mode = 0664
   directory mask = 0775
   force directory mode = 0775
   force user = smbuser
   force group = smb
   follow symlinks = yes
   load printers = no
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = yes
   strict locking = no
   aio read size = 0
   aio write size = 0
   vfs objects = catia fruit recycle streams_xattr
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0
   recycle:repository = .deleted
   recycle:versions = yes

   # Security
   client ipc max protocol = SMB3
   client ipc min protocol = SMB2_10
   client max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = SMB2_10
   server max protocol = SMB3
   server min protocol = SMB2_10

   # Time Machine
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   fruit:time machine = yes
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes


[all]
   path = /smb/all
   browsable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   veto files = /.apdisk/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/.Trashes/desktop.ini/ehthumbs.db/Network Trash Fold
   delete veto files = yes
   valid users = root
```

Comment: How are the shares defined in `smb.conf`?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You have `force group = smb` and `valid users = root`. Are you authenticating as root?

Comment: Yes. I found out that the share works from CLI. This has to be something apple specific since the problem occurs in Finder only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the config line:

```
vfs objects = catia fruit recycle streams_xattr
```

Note the requirements of the [VFS module streams_xattr](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_streams_xattr.8.html):

> The file system that is shared with this module enabled must support xattrs.

After removing `streams_xattr` at least writing once worked. However deleting and writing again made problems. Removing `fruit` alltogether, although using samba only from a mac client, made file operations work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using dperson/samba with a exFAT mount, and was having similar issues with a Windows 10 client giving this error whenever I tried to rename/move/delete (but creating files worked)

> Error 0x80070032: The request is not supported.

as you said, the fix was to remove fruit and streams_xattr from vfs objects line in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
vfs objects = catia recycle
```

```bsh
$ docker exec -it samba bash
$ vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
# in vi, delete fruit and streams_xattr from vfs objects = 
$ exit
$ docker restart samba
```